# How may I get a Thread Exception to terminate just the current command or a WinForms app?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

My .NET Windows Forms app has various commands calling my command functions that can throw exceptions handled by my handler at Application.ThreadException. I would like this handler to terminate the command function without terminating the app, even in the case of a command function that has no try/catch. What's the best way to get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion is to use a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class (as it supports [Cancelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx))

Comment: Thanks, but that would require a lot of code change wince since all my command functions need to access the UI, and IIUC Tasks are not allowed to.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I am not too sure what is IIUC, can u pls explain why Tasks are not allowed?

Comment: IIUC = if I understand correctly. My understanding is that Tasks are not allowed to write to From controls. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ChrisJJ, oh right, yeah that's true, as with any threads, you need to update UI components from one UI thread. But there are workarounds for that, like using Dispatch or Post calls.

Comment: Yes I agree there are workarounds. They substantially complicate the code.

Comment: @ChrisJJ well but there is no other way. UI is processed in one thread and long-running operations in another...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to wrap each of your "commands" in its own try/catch block, which you can do in a fairly generic way. Just catch the exception before it hits the message loop. So if before you had:

```
public void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteCommand("foo");
}
```

you'd have:

```
public void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteInTryCatch(() => ExecuteCommand("foo"));
}

private static void ExecuteInTryCatch(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log exception
    }
}
```

It's worth noting, however, that catching *all* exceptions isn't usually a good idea. If you can, catch very specific exceptions instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not a solution, since the requirements include "even in the case of a command function that has no try/catch". And the reason that I catch all exceptions rather than specific ones is that I do not know which specific ones may be thrown.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: It *is* a solution, because it wraps the command function so that it effectively *does* have try/catch. If you still feel this doesn't meet your needs, perhaps you should clarify exactly what you need - read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions on how to make a question clear.

Comment: @ChrisJJ if *command function that has no try/catch* then your application **must** shut down, you cannot change it, it is the default CLR behaviour. The reason behind it is that your application can be in a totally destroyed state, you never know, so to kill an AppDomain (and your application if it is only one domain in there) is the only safe thing to do.

Comment: @Jon, Your solution is not a solution that meets the stated requirements. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: @oleksii that is not what I see. The CLR behaviour is not to shut down my app. E.g. with a handler only showing a message box, execution continues. If it is a totally destoyed state, I expect AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException - that's not what the question is about.